# "Un-flatten" an RDD in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[LabeledPoint]` of size N.

I would like to transform it to a `RDD[Array[LabeledPoint]]` in a way that all Arrays have roughly the same size (except one smaller if needed).

I have found [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Convert-from-RDD-Object-to-RDD-Array-Object-td9530.html) a method (for an `RDD[Double]`) iterating over RRD's partitions:

```
val batchedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions { iter: Iterator[Int] =>
  new Iterator[Array[Int]] {
    def hasNext: Boolean = iter.hasNext
    def next(): Array[Int] = {
      iter.take(batchedDegree).toArray
    }
  }
}
```

However, in practice, as this method is partitionwise, it creates a lot of Arrays with sizes (much) smaller than the desired one.

I have considered using `coalesce` to reduce the number of partitions and hence the number of smaller Arrays. But this may reduce speed in the latter part of my job.

Do you have other ideas to transform the `RDD` in a better manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rdd.glom()`.

From the Scala docs:

> /**
>   * Return an RDD created by coalescing all elements within each
>   partition into an array.
>   */
>
> ```
>  def glom(): RDD[Array[T]] = withScope
>  {
>      new MapPartitionsRDD[Array[T], T](this, (context, pid, iter) => Iterator(iter.toArray))   
>  }
> ```

Comment: I have seen this feature but this does not give me any control on the array sizes...

Comment: You can achieve this by using `coalesce()` or `repartition()` if you need shuffling.